# What causes garlic leaves to grow through each other splitting them?

Tags: leaves, garlic

It's my first time growing garlic, and it seems like the first cloves I planted have leaves splitting leaves apart, why is that?
[image: garlic growth photo 1]

[image: garlic growth photo 2]

Comment: Please post a photo to show what's happening. Thanks!

Comment: I apologise for the photo angles, I had to use my laptop camera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's common with garlic.  I don't know if there's anything specifically that causes it but you can just separate or split the leaf that's constricting the growth and it'll be fine.

Comment: how far down should I split them, since it does all the way down to the first leaf?

Comment: Your picture shows just one leaf that's restricting the growth.  Where the leaves are popping out of the bottom, just split or remove that one leaf.  The others will grow straight once you free them.  Note that eventually the garlic will do this on its own -- those leaves that are popping out the side will continue to grow and eventually force their way out.